# SQL Server CASE in AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get average of column, where other columns value is 1 or 0 (I can't use where, obviously)

```
select 
      avg(case 
              when 
                  column2 = 1 
              then 
                  column1
              else 
                  0 
              end) 
      as avg1, 
      avg(case 
              when 
                  column2 = 0 
              then 
                  column1
              else 
                  0 
              end) 
       as avg2
```

This won't work, as it is lowering average because it's averages zero in else clause.

Any other similar way?

Thanks.

Comment: @cha sorry, i retyped code, didn't pasted, there is no comma, i edited post...

Comment: Also, I just found that null is working fine instead of 0

Comment: If you want the results in 2 rows use `union` e.g. `select avg(column1) avgWhenCol2is1 from table_name where column2 = 1 union select avg(column1) avgWhenCol2is0 from table_name where column2 = 0`

Comment: can you share a sample o/p. In both case you are trying to get Avg of Column 1. ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have four values in your Table which are the following:

```
 +----------------------
 + Column1     Column2
 +---------------------
 + 100           0
 + 50            0
 + 40            1
 + 80            1
```

If you are using `ELSE 0` that means you are putting `0` on that column and therefore counted as 1 and therefore will be part of your divisor in when you average. So, that you will have this formula

```
Total According Column2 Per Column2 criteria values OVER Total Number of Rows
```

On the case above you have **four (4)** Rows, and therefore it would be like this:

Example for `Column2 = 1`:

```
 (40+80)/4
```

Which is **30**.

Example for `Column2 = 0`:

```
 (100+50)/4
```

Which is **37.5**.

However, if you are using `ELSE NULL` that means you are not including
all the rows but only those that meet the criteria on `WHEN` clause.

On the case above you have **two (2)** for each criteria and therefore would become
the divisor for your Average function.

Example for `Column2 = 1`:

```
 (40+80)/2
```

Which is **60**.

Example for `Column2 = 0`:

```
 (100+50)/2
```

Which is **75**.

See <kbd>**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/339ef/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (column1 + column2) / 
((CASE WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
(CASE WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
(CASE WHEN column1 = 0 AND column2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Average

Hope this Help!!!
```